C# OleDBDatReader not returning any data
I have a query which works perfectly fine when I run it on Oracle SQL Developer, however the same query apparently yields no results when OleDbDataReadeer comes into the picture - when I debug and F11 down to the "while (dr.Read())", it skips over it entirely and goes straight to "dr.Close()". Below is my code;
con.Open();            
OleDbCommand sessioncmd = new OleDbCommand();
sessioncmd.Connection = con;
sessioncmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sessioncmd.CommandText =        " SELECT " +  
                                " NEXTSESS.S_ID" +
                                " ,NEXTSESS.S_REFERENCE " +
                                " ,NEXTSESS.S_ACADEMICYEAR " +
                                " FROM sessiontable SESS join (select s_id, s_reference, s_academicyear,s_name from sessiontable where s_type='AYEAR' and s_academicyear>=to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))  nextsess " +
                                " on nextsess.s_academicyear = SUBSTR(SESS.S_NAME, INSTR(SESS.S_NAME, '/') + 1) " +
                                " WHERE S_TYPE = 'AYEAR'  " +
                                " AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE) between sess.s_start and sess.s_end ";

            OleDbDataReader dr = sessioncmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                decimal SessID = dr.GetDecimal(0);
                string SessRef = "\'" + string.Join("\', \'", dr.GetString(1)) + "\'"; 
                string UnquotedSessRef = dr.GetString(1) ;
                string SessAcademicYear = dr.GetString(2);

                SessionsList.Add(new Sessions
                {
                    S_ID = dr.GetDecimal(0),
                    S_REFERENCE = "\'" + string.Join("\', \'", dr.GetString(1)) + "\'",
                    S_ACADEMICYEAR = dr.GetString(2)
                });

            }
            dr.Close();

As a test, I used a shorter version of the query for the Command Text (shown below) which returns a different set of results altogether but just wanted to test, and this is read fine by the DataReader;
sessioncmd.CommandText =  SELECT 
                                                 SESS.S_ID
                                                 ,SESS.S_REFERENCE 
                                                 ,SESS.S_ACADEMICYEAR 
                                                 FROM sessiontable SESS 
                                                 WHERE S_TYPE = 'AYEAR' 
                                                 and s_academicyear=to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') + 1

I could be completely wrong, but would I be correct in that the DataReader does not accept the lengthy lines? I'm at a loss as the query definitely retrieves data when ran directly on the DB, and I have also tried using a DataAdapter but still no results. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

"would I be correct in that the DataReader does not accept the lengthy lines?" - No, there's no arbitrary limit on the length of the query that can be executed.  (Or at least not one so limiting as to have been reached here.)  If the query is successfully returning 0 records then it's returning 0 records.  Perhaps a mistake was made when confirming that records should be returned?  Perhaps you're accidentally testing against a different database instance?  Perhaps something else?  It sounds like further testing and debugging is needed on your part.

You can narrow down where the problem could be by commenting out the AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE) between sess.s_start and sess.s_end part.

Maybe add an OR 1=1 clause to disable (temporarily) the filter (and make the text even longer). See if you get data then

@AndrewMorton Your suggestion worked! I changed to "AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-24','DD-MON-YY')" and that worked. Thank you so much!

As per Andrew Morton's suggestion, I narrowed down the problem to the Date formatting in the WHERE clause - changed to " AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-24','DD-MON-YY') ".

But why did the same query return rows in Oracle Developer? It's nice and all that you got your query working; but it should have either been broken in both before, since both were running the same query.
